# Access object values in the array

Tags: javascript

In the following example, I would like to access each individual object in the given array. I have tested numerous cases, but still I could able to get the values.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access 0, 450 and 450? Cant you just do `self.dataSeries[0].data[0][1]`?

Answer (score 3):

You can only use the dot to access a property value when the property name is an *IdentifierName*:

> [**11.2.1 Property Accessors**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1)
>
> Properties are accessed by name, using either the dot notation:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression . IdentifierName
> CallExpression . IdentifierName
> ```
>
> or the bracket notation:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression [ Expression ]
> CallExpression [ Expression ]
> ```

But *IdentifierName*s can't begin with a digit:

> [**7.6 Identifier Names and Identifiers**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6)
>
> ```
> IdentifierName ::
>     IdentifierStart
>     IdentifierName IdentifierPart
>
> IdentifierStart ::
>     UnicodeLetter
>     $
>     _
>     \ UnicodeEscapeSequence
>
> UnicodeLetter ::
>     any character in the Unicode categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”, “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”, or “Letter number (Nl)”.
> ```

Therefore, you should use the bracket `[]` notation:

```js
self.dataSeries[0].data[0][0]
```

Moreover, `data[0,1]` may not be what you think. The comma operator evaluates both `0` and `1` expressions, and returns the result of the second one:

> [**11.14 Comma Operator ( , )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14)
>
> The production *Expression* : *Expression* `,` *AssignmentExpression*
>   is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *Expression*.
> 2. Call [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
> 4. Return [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*rref*).

Therefore, `data[0,1]` is exactly the same as `data[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

`self.dataSeries[0].data[0][0]`

Your first attempt was close, but you can't access array indexes with the dot notation, and must use the array notation

Answer (score 1):

You can access your data like this

```
self.dataSeries[0].data[0][0]
```

Pattern is

```
self.dataSeries[parentIndex].data[childIndex][grandChildIndex]
```

Comment: any idea of the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146828/tooltip-kendoui